# java nested e.getActionCommand not working

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I just started learning java GUI and as the title says, I have problem with the getActionCommand. Its a microwave simulation. When the countdown is running and the user pressed stop, it will reset the timer back to 0 (or empty string). CountF is a JLabel while startB is a JButton. Any help will be appreciated

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

    public class Countdown extends JFrame implements ActionListener
    {

    private JLabel countF;
    private JButton oneB;
    private JButton twoB;
    private JButton threeB;
    private JButton fourB;
    private JButton fiveB;
    private JButton sixB;
    private JButton sevenB;
    private JButton eightB;
    private JButton nineB;
    private JButton zeroB;
    private JButton startB;
    private JButton openB;
    private int cookingSeconds;
    private int time;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Countdown demoGui = new Countdown( );
        demoGui.setVisible(true);
    }
    public Countdown()
    {
        super("Microwave");
        this.setSize(700, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
        add(new JLabel("Food to be heated"));
        JPanel rightP = new JPanel();
        add(rightP);
        rightP.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel textP = new JPanel();
        textP.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 50));
        textP.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        countF = new JLabel();
        textP.add(countF);
        rightP.add(textP, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        JPanel tempP = new JPanel();
        rightP.add(tempP, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        tempP.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,3));
        oneB = new JButton("1");
        tempP.add(oneB);
        twoB = new JButton("2");
        tempP.add(twoB);
        threeB = new JButton("3");
        tempP.add(threeB);
        fourB = new JButton("4");
        tempP.add(fourB);
        fiveB = new JButton("5");
        tempP.add(fiveB);
        sixB = new JButton("6");
        tempP.add(sixB);
        sevenB = new JButton("7");
        tempP.add(sevenB);
        eightB = new JButton("8");
        tempP.add(eightB);
        nineB = new JButton("9");
        tempP.add(nineB);
        zeroB = new JButton("0");
        tempP.add(zeroB);
        startB = new JButton("Start");
        tempP.add(startB);
        openB = new JButton("Open");
        tempP.add(openB);
        startB.addActionListener(this);
        openB.addActionListener(this);
        oneB.addActionListener(this);
        twoB.addActionListener(this);
        threeB.addActionListener(this);
        fourB.addActionListener(this);
        fiveB.addActionListener(this);
        sixB.addActionListener(this);
        sevenB.addActionListener(this);
        eightB.addActionListener(this);
        nineB.addActionListener(this);
        zeroB.addActionListener(this);
    }
    public void setCountDownLabelText(String text)
    {
        countF.setText(text);
    }
    public void setOpenBEnable()
    {
        openB.setEnabled(true);
        oneB.setEnabled(true);
        twoB.setEnabled(true);
        threeB.setEnabled(true);
        fourB.setEnabled(true);
        fiveB.setEnabled(true);
        sixB.setEnabled(true);
        sevenB.setEnabled(true);
        eightB.setEnabled(true);
        nineB.setEnabled(true);
        zeroB.setEnabled(true);
    }

    //you need to add the event handling for 1, 2, ...9, 0 buttons to calculate the cookingSeconds.
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource() == startB)
        {
            time = Integer.parseInt(countF.getText());
            cookingSeconds = time;
            new CountDownTimer(this, cookingSeconds).start();
            startB.setText("Stop");
            openB.setEnabled(false);
            oneB.setEnabled(false);
            twoB.setEnabled(false);
            threeB.setEnabled(false);
            fourB.setEnabled(false);
            fiveB.setEnabled(false);
            sixB.setEnabled(false);
            sevenB.setEnabled(false);
            eightB.setEnabled(false);
            nineB.setEnabled(false);
            zeroB.setEnabled(false);
            if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Stop"))
            {
                // this is not working
                countF.setText("");
            }
        }
        else if (e.getSource() == openB)
        {
            countF.setText("");
        }
        else if (e.getSource() == oneB)
        {
            countF.setText(countF.getText() + "1");
        }
        else if (e.getSource() == twoB)
        {
            countF.setText(countF.getText() + "2");
        }
        else if (e.getSource() == threeB)
        {
            countF.setText(countF.getText() + "3");
        }
        else if (e.getSource() == fourB)
        {
            countF.setText(countF.getText() + "4");
        }
        else if (e.getSource() == fiveB)
        {
            countF.setText(countF.getText() + "5");
        }
        else if (e.getSource() == sixB)
        {
            countF.setText(countF.getText() + "6");
        }
        else if (e.getSource() == sevenB)
        {
            countF.setText(countF.getText() + "7");
        }
        else if (e.getSource() == eightB)
        {
            countF.setText(countF.getText() + "8");
        }
        else if (e.getSource() == nineB)
        {
            countF.setText(countF.getText() + "9");
        }
        else if (e.getSource() == zeroB)
        {
            countF.setText(countF.getText() + "0");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to get value of `ActionCommand` from `Button` while you are getting it from event which will give you the *old value* because you are setting text inside `if` block as you also need to `setActionCommand` on that point.

```
 if("Stop".equals(startB.getActionCommand())){//To avoid NullPointer
       countF.setText("");
 }
```

Comment: +1 for differentiating between the button action command and the event action command.

Comment: so do I need to setActionCommand as well inside the if? Sorry I'm new to Java @TAsk

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell why your code isn't working without guessing, but anyway here goes -- perhaps you have never set the actionCommand to "Stop". If so, then the if block will never run. Note that if you set the text of a JButton via `setText(...)` this will **not** automatically set the actionCommand.

If this doesn't help, consider taking a little time to create and post a [minimal example program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that we'll fully understand your problem and not have to guess.

---

My guess is correct -- you never set the button's actionCommand as I don't see setActionCommand(...) being called anywhere.

Myself, I'd give each group of unique buttons there own ActionListeners or Actions, and would let them handle this sort of thing, rather than having a "switchboard" type of listener. For example,...

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class StartStopActionTest {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Action startStopAction = new StartStopAction("Start", KeyEvent.VK_S, "Stop", KeyEvent.VK_S);
      JButton startStopButton = new JButton(startStopAction);
      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.add(startStopButton);
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);
   }
}

class StartStopAction extends AbstractAction {
   private String startText;
   private int startMnemonic;
   private String stopText;
   private int stopMnemonic;


   public StartStopAction(String startText, int startMnemonic, String stopText,
         int stopMnemonic) {
      super(startText);
      putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, startMnemonic);
      this.startText = startText;
      this.startMnemonic = startMnemonic;
      this.stopText = stopText;
      this.stopMnemonic = stopMnemonic;
   }


   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      if (getValue(NAME).equals(startText)) {
         putValue(NAME, stopText);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, stopMnemonic);

         // start action code here

      } else {
         putValue(NAME, startText);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, startMnemonic);

         // stop action code here

      }
   }
}
```

Comment: @bisonsausage: my guess is correct -- you never set the button's actionCommand as I don't see `setActionCommand(...)` being called anywhere.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your new code. By the setActionCommand, is it something that looks like startB.setActionCommand("Stop"); ?

Comment: `Note that if you set the text of a JButton via setText(...) this will not automatically set the actionCommand.` You don't need to call setActionCommand() explicitly. The getActionCommand() method will return the text value when the action command is null. The OP is setting the text to "Stop" which will change the value returned from the getActionCommand() method, however, the code is checking for the event action command which was still "Start" at the time the event was generated.